# ping a port with specific packet /my own packet

Tags: linux, networking

Is there a way to ping a specific port with my own packetsize ? 
Can I create my own packets lets say using a packet builder and send them without a MAC address of the receiving machine ?

Comment: this question is unclear. by "PING" do you specifically mean sending an ICMP packet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#ICMP_packet)? Pings are sent with IP addresses, not MAC addresses, do I don't know why you're asking about that.

Answer (score 1):

1) Ping is simply a specific type of ICMP Message. ICMP Messages sit directly on top of IP and thus there's no concept of a port, since that's introduced by TCP.

2) You must specify a MAC Address in all your packets. It can be the one of the device you're trying to ping.

Comment: actually, ports are used in many different IP protocols (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers), not just TCP. you probably already know that UDP also has the concept of ports.

Comment: right I should have said ports are introduced in the transport layer, not just in TCP. Regardless, these are not IP protocols. IP is a protocol. These are protocols that sit on top of IP.